# Adding Printer to a workgroup client

Tags: windows, network-printer

We have a color printer connected locally to a workstation that has been joined to a domain (which runs windows xp). I need to add this printer to a workstation that hasn't been joined to the domain. I used unc path and added this printer to the workgroup workstation, but every time that this client shuts down the pc or restarts it the connection to the printer will be lost and we need to add it again. Is there any way to add it permanently?

Comment: Which client do you reboot that causes this? And which PC is it removed from?

Answer (score 0):

The printer should still be there after you reboot the workstation.

Have you check your logs ? Could be a credential error, or something like that. Maybe the workstation can't remember the credential used to log on the domain computer. You can "Check" Remember password for future use when you install the printer.

You could add a script in All User > startup to connect to the printer ( not elegant but it works). If you choose a script, you will have to put credential in the script, might try to use a bogus account only used to connected to that machine for that printer.